# Jquery ui sortable on specified table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i am using the `HTML` Table with some data being dynamically added to the table.
There are two columns in the table `id` & `title`. I am using `jQuery UI` sortable to sort the table rows. The `HTML` and `JS` are as below:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="questions-list-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>                    
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td>Title 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 2 </td>
                    <td> Title 2</td>
                </tr>               
            </tbody>
        </table>

            <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#questions-list-table tbody").sortable({
            disableSelection: true,
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            axis:"y",
            stop: function(e) {
                console.log("Sorting started");
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Currently whole row is getting sorted. I want that only title to be sortable, the `id` column should remain in its original place. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the id column is a sequential number starting with 1 then, one possible solution is t

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var start;
  $("#questions-list-table tbody").sortable({
    disableSelection: true,
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    axis: "y",
    start: function(e, ui) {
      start = ui.item.index();
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      var end = ui.item.index();

      var from = start <= end ? start : end,
        to = start <= end ? end + 1 : start + 1;
      $("#questions-list-table tbody > tr").slice(from, to).find('td:first').text(function(i) {
        return from + i + 1;
      })
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="questions-list-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Title 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Title 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Title 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Title 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort one only column at a time.

so you didn't need to match the corresponding value of the individual rows.

**If this is your case**(this is not Bootstrap Case), Try to implement as two individual table with one column

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks...but your solution is not viable,as i had stated earlier,the content is dynamic in my table. so the height of table cell can vary. So it would be very difficult to maintain the concurrency of id and title...Hope you understood my reason...

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to sort just one column then the only option is two use two tables as @vijay kani said.

First table will contain only ID column and the Second will contain the Title column. Then you can use css to give it the look of just one table. After that just make the second table sortable.

Here is an example

```js
$("#questions-title-table tbody").sortable({
  disableSelection: true,
  axis: "y"
});
```

```css
#questions-id-table {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table id="questions-id-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="questions-title-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also an [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s41aja7m/)